# How do I add a link to my HTML page with out affecting the other functionality in the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I added one new link in a webpage. it works fine, but when I hit a link, one blank is coming with that page. I know the reason: it’s because of `<iframe>` in the bottom. I am adding the code below.

My question is "how to add without affecting other links" or changing functionality in other web page?

In the first web page, I added this link:

```
<%-- Access the <a href="javascript:navigate('/common/Link.aspx?linkid=SecureAPI&amp;JumpID=Products.ResourceCenter.Operations.AnnuityOrderEntry')">A.O.E.One-Stop-Shop</a> in the Resource Center for further information and instructions.--%>
```

This link is affected by an `<iframe>` in the same page.

```
<iframe name="TimeoutFrameLPL" id="TimeoutFrame" src="blank.htm" width="1px" height="1px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The `<iframe>` is calling in another webpage. Due to this I am getting a blank page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setDocDomain();

var lastID = '0';

var qs = new String(location.search);
var target = 'AnnuityLandingPage.aspx'+qs;

function getCommFrame()
    {
    var iwin;
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
    {
        iwin = frames["TimeoutFrame"];
    }else{
        iwin = window.open('', "TimeoutFrame");
    }
    return iwin;
    }
```

What are the changes required in the two webpages for not displaying that blank page? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `<iframe style="display:none" />` ?

if you set the attribute style of an element to `display:none`, the browser will skip its rendering

Comment: hi mic, where you want me to try this ?

Comment: I understood that you get a blank element appearing at the end of your page. Probably the IFRAME. So I suggest to add an attribute `style="display:none"` to that IFRAME (may be the one with `name="TimeoutFrameLPL"`)

Comment: mic, i got you. i will try that. actually in getcommframe() function. i think due to window.open call,i am getting that blank page. is it the reason for that blank page?.... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a `target`?  I believe this is what you need, such as: `<a href='my.awesome.site.com target="myFrame">Load Page</a>`

Comment: you mean,i have to add that link in frame?